# Does it ever make sense to send assistant heroquesters?

Tags: king-of-dragon-pass

Two heroquests offer you the option of sending a 'helper' heroquester, but I have the impression that this only ever reduces the chance of succeeding in the quest.  Is this true?  If so, are there any benefits at all to sending a helper heroquester?

Answer (score 1):

If you provide a helper, the quester doesn’t have to convince a god to join the quest. So on “Issaries the Conciliator,” two fewer chances to fail. On  the other hand, the gods are more powerful.